# React multiple import one module caching re-use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, react-router

I am using `Centrifugo` websocket server. I need to connect to `Centrifugo` and store connection `instance` for future usage from from multiple `components`.

Will it be the good way to create this kind of export from `./socket.js`? 
Will `centrifuge.connect()` and `centrifuge.setToken('')` be executed if I gonna import `./socket.js` module muitiple times?

`./socket.js`

```
const Centrifuge = require('centrifuge');

const centrifuge = new Centrifuge('ws://localhost:8000/connection/websocket');
centrifuge.setToken('');
centrifuge.connect();

export default {
    socket: centrifuge,
};
```

`./App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { socket } from '../socket'; // first import
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent';
import SomeSecondComponent from './components/SomeSecondComponent';

export default () => (
    <>
        <SomeComponent />
        <SomeSecondComponent />
    </>
)
```

`./components/SomeComponent.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { socket } from '../socket'; // second import

export default () => <>...</>;
```

`./components/SomeSecondComponent.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { socket } from '../socket'; // third import

export default () => <>...</>;
```

What would it be the best way to make instance and reuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a single instance only, it's better to import it in one place only. Best to import in the parent component and pass it as props to the children.

So your `app.jsx` would become:

```
import React from 'react';
import { socket } from '../socket'; // first import
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent';
import SomeSecondComponent from './components/SomeSecondComponent';

export default () => (
    <>
        <SomeComponent socket={socket} />
        <SomeSecondComponent socket={socket} />
    </>
)
```

Now socket will be available as the props in both the components.

For eg. In `./components/SomeComponent.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({socket}) => <>...</>;
```

Comment: Is there some other good way to use it?
I am using react-router and need to pass socket instance for each route? Almost every component use socket.

Comment: You can use `React Context` for this case.

Comment: Add this in the parent `App.jsx`:

`export const Socket = React.createContext(socket);`

You can use `React.useContext(Socket)` to extract the instance. 

This [Doc](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) might help you understand about the context.